# Ghost website not working on Ec2 with Amazon certificate and Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, ghost-blog

I installed Ghost on my EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18 by following the [official guide](https://ghost.org/docs/install/ubuntu/).

I didn't opt-in for a LetsEncrypt certificate though. I wanted to roll my own with the Amazon Certificate Manager and load-balance requests to the website via Route53 and a CloudFront distribution.

The issue is that the blog doesn't load - instead I am presented the [default nginx homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVOo0.jpg).

This is my website config in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name paulrberg.com;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

I suspect that the issue is the nginx configuration. The way Ghost provides may not be compatible with an Amazon certificate coupled with Route53 and CloudFront.

Is this even doable or do I have to use the LetsEncrypt certificate and give up on my infrastructure of choice?

Comment: You have configured Nginx here to use only port 80. Is that what you wanted or you want  HTTPS also?

Comment: For testing purposes HTTP works. In production I'll switch to HTTPS.